# nullable constraint does not have any effect on column in mysql table

Tags: grails

I have the created the following domain class

```
class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

String username
String password
String mobile
String email
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

static belongsTo = [organization  : Organization,
                    branch        : Branch,
                    student       : Student]

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    (UserRole.findAllByUser(this) as List<UserRole>)*.role as Set<Role>
}

static constraints = {
    password blank: false, password: true
    username blank: false, unique: true
    organization nullable: true
    branch nullable: true
    student nullable: true
    email nullable: true
    mobile nullable: true
} }
```

But when I check the User table in mysql, it is showing still branch, organization and student NOT NULL

I maintained hasOne association in related Domains. for example

```
class Organization { ... static hasOne = [user: User] }
```

I doubt, does hasOne have any effect on that

Comment: I dropped the db and run again, still same no effect

Comment: remove references from `belongsTo`

Answer (score 0):

hasOne creates a not null constraints. You have to use the hasMany relationship in related domains for not null to work.